# Trying to get a color value within 10 shades

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, graphics, gdi+

In my code I get the pixel color of a given coordinate and I then check to see if that color matches another color. It works great, now I want to be able to check if it matches within 10 or so shades of the color or a set amount of shades. I have no idea how to do this though. Here is the code:

```
     Public Function GetPixelColor(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Color

    Dim sz As New Size(1, 1)
    Dim c As Color

    Using bmp As New Bitmap(1, 1)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

            g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(x, y), Point.Empty, sz)
            c = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0)

        End Using
    End Using

    Return c

End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fb As Color = GetPixelColor(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
    If fb.ToArgb() = TextBox3.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Rock on dude")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Shading is mixing the color with black to reduce lightness, is this what you mean?

Comment: No not at all. I meant the shades of color.

Comment: Ok well you're talking about the _hue_, not the shade. Because shade is the mixture with black, while the color is unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a function like this and make a call to it with both colors:

```
Private Function CompareColors(ByVal Color1 As Color, ByVal Color2 As Color) As Boolean
    If Color1.ToArgb = Color2.ToArgb Then
        'perfect match
        Return True
    ElseIf Asc(Color1.R) > Asc(Color2.R) - 10 AndAlso Asc(Color1.R) < Asc(Color2.R) + 10 Then
        ' red is wrong
        Return False
    ElseIf Asc(Color1.G) > Asc(Color2.G) - 10 AndAlso Asc(Color1.G) < Asc(Color2.G) + 10 Then
        ' green is wrong
        Return False
    ElseIf Asc(Color1.B) > Asc(Color2.B) - 10 AndAlso Asc(Color1.B) < Asc(Color2.B) + 10 Then
        ' blue is wrong
        Return False
    ElseIf Asc(Color1.A) > Asc(Color2.A) - 10 AndAlso Asc(Color1.A) < Asc(Color2.A) + 10 Then
        ' alpha is wrong
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This solution is likely to be a bottleneck because it is called for *pairs of single pixels*. The initial `perfect match` test will only slow things down for the vastly more likely case where the colours are different. Also, you are calculating a cube of colour tolerance instead of the more usual sphere. And you are calculating every colour-pair's difference twice instead of using the absolute value just once

Comment: Borodin, you're right, I wouldn't use this in something that checked a large number of pixels. But it does demonstrate some useful parts of the Color object. As always, if you have a better solution, feel free to post it. Mathematically this is not great.

Comment: I can't write reliable VB, but I am sure you can interpret my comment. The first `If` clause should be dropped, and each of the RGB tests should be on the absolute value of the difference. Progressing to a spherical space needs just a comparison of the sum of the squares of the three differences with the square of the limit - i.e. 100 here

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the language you're using, but it sounds like you need to compute the absolute value of the difference between the color values.

pseudocode:

```
if( Abs(color1 - color2) > 10.0 )
  // do something
```